# Print from Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to add a functionality to connect and print in my application.

Please can someone suggest how can I do that? Is there some API available which can be used to connect the Windows Phone 8 to a printer.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Windows Phone 8 programming, but have you tried looking at the SDK documentation?

Comment: yes there are certain apps that have alreadt implemented the same, may be by using bluetooth, so just wanted help as in how is this done.

Comment: Here's a number of search results: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=windows+phone+8+printing

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option available to you will be to use a portable Bluetooth printer. Depending on the actual device you use will impact exactly how to print to it.

Documentation on using Bluetooth with Windows Phone 8 can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207007(v=vs.105).aspx